# HTTPConnectionPool(host='http_proxy=<ip>, port=<port>): Max retries exceeded with url: <url>

Tags: python, proxy, http-proxy, urllib3

When I make requests.post, I get an error like this: "**HTTPConnectionPool(host='http_proxy=, port=): Max retries exceeded with url:  (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000246DDDB14B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')))**".

This problem occurred after adding the proxy. I removed the proxy, but interestingly the problem still persists. Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.